# SAS - Recognize missing values when reading CSV

Tags: sas

Given the csv:

```
Cat,,9
Dog,,10
Egg,,11
```

And the code:

```
DATA database ;
INFILE '/path/to/data' dlm=',' missover;
INPUT 
    animal $
    missing $ 
    number 
    ;
RUN;
```

The output I get is:

```
animal   missing   number
Cat      9        
Dog      10       
Egg      11
```

How can I get SAS to recognize the missing value, so that my output table is like the one below?

```
animal   missing   number
Cat                9        
Dog                10       
Egg                11
```

Comment: in your 'Infile' statement, add 'DSD' option, after that, dlm=',' becomes redundant.

Comment: @HaikuoBian Answers should go into 'answers' not comments. Don't short sell yourself. =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to include `dsd` in your `infile` statement as this signifies that SAS should treat two consecutive commas as a missing value. You can read more information [here](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000146932.htm):

```
DATA database ;
INFILE '/path/to/data' dlm=',' missover dsd;
INPUT 
    animal $
    missing $ 
    number 
    ;
RUN;
```